# BeautifulSoup + Unicode, Dammit - html garbled despite charset specified in meta tag

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse http://www.olx.pt/carros-cat-378-p-1. By changing the last number in the url, I can iterate through the pages. The page specifies ISO-8859-1 in Content-Type in a meta tag. Thus, I tell that to BeautifulSoup in the from_encoding argument.

However, every now and then, when doing a find_all, I get a zero-length resultset. Inspecting the soup, I see that *everything* gets garbled. I've tried to catch when I get a zero ResultSet and a switch to a different charset, e.g. cp1252 and latin1.

I think it's really weird that all the HTML gets garbled, and only every now and then. I also think it's even really weird that I can't figure out which charset is being used when this happens. Does anyone have a clue what could be going on here?

Code

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def getNewBrowser():
    # create browser instance
    b = mechanize.Browser()

    # create a cookiejar for cookies
    jar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    b.set_cookiejar(jar)

    # prevent mechanize from simulating a 403 disallow
    b.set_handle_robots(False)

    # handle some other stuff
    b.set_handle_equiv(True)
    #b.set_handle_gzip(True)
    b.set_handle_redirect(True)
    b.set_handle_referer(True)

    # follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh >0
    b.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

    # want debugging messages?
    #br.set_debug_http(True)
    #br.set_debug_redirects(True)
    #br.set_debug_responses(True)

    # User-Agent
    b.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0')]
    return b



def run():
    b = getNewBrowser()
    url = "http://www.olx.pt/carros-cat-378-p-"
    n = 100
    for i in range(1,n):
        urlt = url + str(i)
        b.open(urlt, timeout = 10.0)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(b.response(), from_encoding="ISO-8859-1")
        print "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
        print "page: " + str(i)
        print "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
        print soup


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: could you be a little more specific as to this garbling thing ?

Comment: Yeah, looks like this: <html><body><p>ï¿½      ï¿½Wï¿½nï¿½6ï¿½nï¿½ï¿½ï¿½mDï¿½ï¿½$ï¿ etc.etc....

Comment: could be utf-8 read in something else. did you try `file` to guess the encoding ?

Comment: @user2149075: Could you maybe intercept the raw binary form of a garbled file and upload the whole thing somewhere so we can poke at it? Also it'd help if you could say what the text in it is supposed to be. That is unless it's confidential somehow. Also, what does "every now and then mean"? Does this happen only for some URLs, or just completely randomly?

Comment: @millimoose I'll do that in a sec and post link. In the meantime: no, it's not confidential. URL in code, but use this: http://www.olx.pt/carros-cat-378-p-1. Change the last digit to jump from page to page. It's in Portuguese. By every now and then I mean that for some of the pages (say, change to "p-2" in the url), it'll suddenly be garbled. Other times, it'll be correct (i.e. readable). Looks random. The data on a given page changes alot though, because users are interacting with it and I suspect that's why it's "random".

Comment: @millimoose File that was correct: http://www.filedropper.com/1_62

Comment: @millimoose Garbled file: http://www.filedropper.com/2_18

Comment: @millimoose Both files were obviously downloaded with the same code. First url is http://www.olx.pt/carros-cat-378-p-1, the second is http://www.olx.pt/carros-cat-378-p-2.

Comment: @njzk2 Do you mean saving the html-file to disk and visually checking or do mean specifying another attribute (file). Not familiar with that one...

Comment: save the html file, then look at it to see what encoding it is using

Comment: @njzk2 OK, so I simply saved the html to disk and looked at the source in notepad and that looks fine. charset = ISO-8859-1. Exactly what I'm telling BeautifulSoup it is.

Comment: @njzk2 Alright, so it says Western European (ISO) when I save the file. I tried with various ISO encodings, but no joy. Still the same type of error... How come I can save the file as htm and open it in notepad with everything ungarbled, but when I use BeautifulSoup or urllib it gets screwed up half the time?

Comment: @user2149075 Hm. That /is/ bizarre. And you're saving the contents of `b.response()` to the text files, right?

Comment: @millimoose Yup. I've no clue what the hell is going on. Could it be something with the headers? Maybe some cookies that aren't being sent back? Or maybe it's.... shit. Maybe it's gzip on some pages?

Comment: @user2149075 I tried hitting the pages randomly with `wget --save-headers` and noticed no discrepancies. The page `…-p-1` does have different headers, and a broken cookie header, but unless that's the only one that comes in mangled, or the only one that doesn't, it's probably not relevant. Besides, the headers shouldn't matter if you're using the response body as the byte array and hardcode the encoding. Maybe it's actually an intermittent bug in BeautifulSoup? Try and decode the same response twice, look for an element you know is in it, then check for a difference?

Comment: (I'll admit I'm now at the wild guessing stage though.)

Comment: @millimoose I tried a bit of that, but I actually got it now! Page 1 is being presented as-is, but all the other pages are being gzipped (or at least most of them!), so i just put in my header that I accept gzip, and then I just do a try/except to see if the response cotains a header for content-encoding = gzip. If so, I just un-gzip it, et voilá! That is the weirdest thing I've seen!

Comment: @user2149075 Aha! I must've missed the gzip header for the cookie error message. I'd have thought Mechanize would handle that transparently somehow. (Or maybe it does but `response()` is the wrong method to use.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace() to replace the encoding declared in the page content by "utf-8". It's a bit hackish, but that's what worked for me.

Before passing the page content to BeautifulSoup:

```
page_content.replace('charset="ISO-8859-1"','charset=utf-8')
```

Comment: Nice trick - I'll keep that in mind if I run into something similar down the road. Thanks!